# NexentaStor 3.1.5-GA (community ed) won't boot from a CD

Tags: zfs, nexenta

I can boot from 3.1.5-GA ISO into a VirtualBox VM. But when I boot from a bootable CD, it stops at "Grub Stage2", and then drops me into a grub rescue shell after a few seconds..

I know very well how to burn bootable CDs etc. I have used 2 different CDs, burnt them with 2 different programs, tried to boot different machines with different CD drives.

Why can't it go beyond grub's Stage-2? Any thoughts, experiences? Or should I try older versions? if anybody knows about their archived release, please share? Their forums are too slow. Or should I stick to FreeNAS, or better yet learn ZFS the hard-way?

Edit: If I use an older release, would their license generation work with that older release? I don't think they would support older releases..

Comment: :( I'd keep looking. Nexenta isn't a great choice right now.

Comment: Why do you say that Sir? I think you say so because Nexenta isn't playing well with the community any more, their publicly available beta releases are too old, they don't share any nightly builds anymore?

Comment: Learn ZFS the hard way. In the past I've used both FreeNAS and Nexenta, and in both cases, I ended up wanting to do things with ZFS that weren't exposed in their GUI, meaning that I needed to learn the ZFS cli commands anyway. Install FreeBSD and learn things from the ground up - you'll be much more future-proof that way.

Comment: @Junaid All of the above... I've been using [ZFS on Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org) with RHEL/CentOS mainly since Nexenta stopped being responsive to my needs.

Comment: @ewwhite: According to this (http://zfsonlinux.org/faq.html#PerformanceConsideration), ZFS-on-Linux is not yet optimized for performance, so probably actual ZFS with "tiered" storage is the way to go for building efficient storage arrays.. Probably FreeNAS/NAS4free would be the easier way to go for any easy-to-manage ZFS install. FreeNAS lets one very easily configure LARC and ZILs from the GUI just like nexenta.

Comment: Go for it. ZFS on Linux performance is just fine, though.

Comment: @ewwhite: Thanks for that feedback regarding ZFS on Linux! When would btrFS be production ready? I don't want to learn FreeBSD or Solaris :(

Comment: btrFS has lost momentum. ZFS is actually stable on Linux

Comment: Well I still have hopes about it.. Their [Wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page#News) and articles such as [this](http://www.zdnet.com/btrfs-hands-on-exploring-the-error-recovery-features-of-the-new-linux-file-system-7000024053/) suggest that dev work is on going.. I really won't want it to end up like tux3.  Also I tried to PXE-boot Nexenta 3.1.5 and 3.1.1 on a DL380 G5, and it didn't work. There was some error regarding not being able to relocate amd64 miniroot.. Just mentioning it here so that others might use this info, if need be.

Comment: @Junaid It should install natively on an HP ProLiant DL380 G5.

Comment: Yes it did install actually.. I was burning CDs with bad writers prior to that..Though I can confirm that it causes a kernel dump/crash/panic when booted on an ML 350 G5.

Comment: Download a new .iso file from thier site. It seems to be a problem with the image